# Can other Shifters enter Weretouched Master?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, races, eberron, polymorph

The Weretouched Master is supposed to be designed for shifters of any bloodline right? So why are Bear, Boar, Rat, Tiger, Wolf and Wolverine the only bloodlines with listed info.? Shifters are supposed to be descended from any type of lycanthrope you choose that qualifies for lycanthropy in the first place right? So if I wanted to be descended from a Were-Hyena, or even one of the Truedive shifters ancestors (like Were-shark) or a Saurian Shifter from Dragon Magazine 328, how would Weretouched Master interact with that? Do I need to merely choose a seemingly appropriate bloodlines stats from those listed or are any non listed bloodlines barred from the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two real options here. First is to homebrew new options for the prestige class, to accommodate new shifter lines. The second is to pick one of the existing options that is similar to your shifter line in terms of flavor and function. For instance, if you want to play a velociraptor shifter, raptors were reasonably similar to wolves in how they hunted as a pack to bring down large herbivores, so pick the "wolf" option and flavor it as "raptor".

Answer (score 1):

The various shifter types are **not** associated with some particular animal heritage. Nothing in *Eberron Campaign Setting*, which introduces the shifters and their original options of beasthide, cliffwalk, longstride, longtooth, razorclaw, and wildhunt, indicates that any of these shifters descend specifically from any animal. And when *Races of Eberron* introduces other shifters—dreamsight, gorebrute, swiftwing, and truedive—it also did not associate any of them with any particular animal.

The weretouched master prestige class, also introduced in *Eberron Campaign Setting*, is actually the only place that does discuss the specific were-animal a given shifter might be descended from. That means that any shifter, regardless of their shifting, may choose any lycanthrope heritage for the weretouched feature of weretouched master. So a swiftwing shifter or truedive shifter who becomes a weretouched master would have the same options—bear, boar, rat, tiger, wolf, or wolverine—as any other shifter.

In fact, the only source that suggests that any particular type of shifter is descended from any particular type of animal is—***maybe***—*Tome of Battle*. The Shifters and the Bloodclaw Master sidebar notes that shifters receive different benefits from the bloodclaw master prestige class, and one of those is counting as razorclaw for prerequisites. Since bloodclaw master is all about the Tiger Claw discipline, and the shifting feature it offers most (read: non-shifter) characters is explicitly “like a tiger,” that implies an association between razorclaw shifters and tigers.

And while it is unclear why this particular facet of shifters and the weretouched master didn’t get more attention, one plausible reason is that *neither shifter nor weretouched master turned out very well*. Shifters are maybe as good as other races *while shifting*, which means they’re quite a bit weaker when they aren’t, and weretouched master again locks most of its benefit behind starkly-limited-uses-per-day shifting.

Answer (score 0):

It would require a DM ruling.

The developers didn't create a bullet point for every 'what if' scenario available. Some were added after the fact, hence Dragon magazine. If you want to have a bloodline that falls out of the published material provided, who would arbitrate the bloodlines from other animals? It would have to be your DM.

Comment: Whereas I can understand the DM thing, I was specifically wondering whether WoTC had answered a similar question which would be official or if this had come up before perhaps. On another note, Truedive trait shifters are not outside the original published material for shifters, so were-shark descendants should've been covered yet they strangely weren't so I was also curious as to whether there was a specific reason for this.